# Getting Uncaught Reference Error when changing the function of a button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get a button to display a modal when it's when an element has a child node. So when you click on it, it would activate the function and display the modal accordingly, it would do this by adding the id "myBtn" to the `button` element.

This is my HTML:

```
<li id='parentNode'>
  <button onclick="child_check()" id="button" class='customer-btn'><a href='#'>Customer 6</a></button>
  <ul>
    <li id='childNode'>
      <a href='#'>Customer A</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

And this is my JS:

```
<script>

    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementById(" myBtn");
    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    btn.onclick = function() {
       modal.style.display = "block";
    }


    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
  }
    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it

// Check to see if the list element has a child
function child_check() {
  var child = document.getElementById("childNode");
  var parent_check = document.getElementById("parentNode").contains(child);
  var parent = document.getElementById("parentNode")
  var button = document.getElementById("button")
  if (parent_check){
    button.id += " myBtn";
    // Code that activates modal
    // Get the modal

    // When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 

  }
}


</script>
```

### Edit

Seems to be working, still getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contains' of null at child_check (profile:259)

Comment: `it would do this by adding the id "myBtn" to the button element`  - actually it would change the id from `parentNode` to `parentNodemyBtn` - if only `getElementById` were a function - did you mean `document.getElementById` perhaps

Comment: @JaromandaX is correct regarding your id adjustment-- you probably want `=` not `+=`.  Also: "and display the modal accordingly, it would do this by adding the id "myBtn" to the button element" -- are you asserting that simply adding an ID to an element will launch a modal?  Because that sounds wrong...

Comment: @JaromandaX Hey sorry for the late reply, thanks I didn't even realize I was referencing the id, not the actual element. I just want to add a new id to the parent element

Comment: @JaromandaX And I didn't realize I forgot "document" from that function call, thanks I'm gonna keep working on this

Comment: Updated the code, now I'm getting the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contains' of null
    at child_check (profile:259)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (VM2771 profile:149)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modal aside (I see no modal code here), you could probably add a space to your `+= " myBtn"` line like so, to successfully give the button an ID of 'myBtn'. If not, just use a plain "=" and give it all the IDs it needs, separated by a space.

Comment: I updated my question with the modal code, I'm still having issues

Comment: As far as I can tell, parentNode is not a variable. You try to reference it, but haven't defined it anywhere. Also when you're setting parentNode.id, if all you're giving it is 1 ID, you don't need a space. If it already has an ID, and you want to give it another ID, you would use += and prepend that ID with a space so it knows the new ID is seperate from the one you're adding it to. In other words, make it say `id="oldID newID"` instead of `id="oldIDnewID"`

Comment: Do you mean when I referenced it in the parameter? Is that not how you're supposed to use that function?

Comment: I redacted my last comment. The immediate issue I see is that you haven't defined a parentNode variable, but are setting parentNode.id.  Which is basically saying nothing.id = something

Comment: Okay so it seems to be working, what I did was I moved the JS from my JS file and pasted it into my html file. I also updated it with the variable `parent` (now that's the node with the `parentNode` id) that would have it's id changed. The only issue seems to be when I view the console and get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contains' of null
    at child_check (profile:259)`

Comment: @Amon In your HTML, always use double quotes when defining element attributes. `id="parentNode"`

Comment: Okay thanks, I noticed that I only get that `TypeError` after pressing the button more than once

Comment: @Amon you're trying to add class myBtn to your LI element, parentNode. It's not a button. You're setting a button click function on the actual button using onClick, and then in child check you are instantiating a new click handler (every time) on the LI parentNode which now is no longer `id="parentNode"` but at that point the ID has been changed to `id=" myBtn"`

Comment: Okay so basically I need to give the `" myBtn"` to `<button>`?

Comment: @Amon yes that's one thing. The other problem that will make you run into is that you will be defining multiple click handlers on the button. Initially, it will use your html onClick=, but then when child check runs once, you are defining a new click handler, and additionally parentNode will not exist anymore because you're not adding myBtn you're replacing it by using = instead of +=.  Do you understand what I meant in my first comment on this answer?

Comment: Yes I do, sorry. I edited the code again. However now the modal isn't loading at all. Should I have it so there is only one event handler?

Comment: @ Amon 1 click handler per id/class, take handlers out of your function, let them be defined on page load, avoid onClick as an HTML parameter.

Comment: Okay Im having a hard to understanding, how would I have one handler per id and not use `onclick()`?

Comment: You're using onClick twice. Once to call child check (in the HTML button element) and then in child check, you are defining a bunch of JavaScript onclicks. While the JavaScript way is the way to go, and not the HTML way, your JavaScript onclick functions should be defined so they don't get defined when child check is called, but instead as soon as the document has loaded.

Comment: @Amon Also your `window.onclick` function will trigger a click no matter where in the window you click, even if it's a modal. So take that part out because you don't want it to trigger every time a click occurs in your browser window

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138881/discussion-between-amon-and-bango).